# Inserting date as dd-mon-yy in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to insert date value as dd-mon-yy but the database is storing it as dd/mm/yy.

For example: INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (to_date('01-mar-09', 'dd-mon-yy');

The DB stores it as 01/03/09. Why is that? Whay can't I just store it as 01-mar-09?

Please help.

Comment: what tool are you using to display the data? what is the NLS_DATE setting?

Comment: `select to_char(dt, 'dd-mon-yy') from tablename` ?

Comment: Not relevant to the question really, but is there a reason you're still using 2-digit years? Why not use `01-Mar-2009`, or a non-NLS-language dependent version like `01/03/2009`, or even an ANSI date literal like `date '2009-03-01'`?

Comment: A date in Oracle does not have any format! "01/03/09" is just according to your current `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting.

Comment: in addition to the answers below, it's worth noting that when you've stored something as a DATE datatype, you have to tell Oracle how you want to display the date when you view it. You can either rely on the implicit conversion (which is where Oracle will convert the DATE into a string using the format defined by the nls_date_format parameter), or you can convert the DATE explicitly, using `TO_CHAR(<date_value>, '<date format>'`, eg. `to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'`. Generally, you'd use the former for ad-hoc queries, and the latter for production code, where appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date is a raw datatype. It doesn't have a format to be saved. It's upto you or the environment/session to decide how to display it.. use `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter as required... using alter session or use `to_char()` function

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-YY';
select sysdate from dual;
28-OCT-15

alter session set nls_date_format = 'MM/DD/YY';
select sysdate from dual;
10/28/15
```

The NLS parameters precedence is decided as below, if not set on session level then use instance level, if not set at instance level then use which is present at database level. Below are the views which provide set values at each level

```
NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS => session level parameters
NLS_INSTANCE_PARAMETERS => instance level parameters
NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS => database level parameters
```

Comment: Are you saying that by executing the nls_date_format query, I will then be able to store the date in the format I want ?

Comment: I ran the first two commands you posted and the result does not show as 28-oct-15.. It still shows 10/28/2015

Comment: @Stranger - no, you do not store the date in any format. You just store a date, which Oracle has its own internal representation for. You can convert a string to a date for storage (with `to_date()`), or you can convert a date to a string for display (with `to_char()`). The NLS_DATE_FORMAT is used for both of those when you do an implicit conversion or don't supply your own format mask. If you want to see the date in a specific format, use `to_char()` and supply that format model. Don't rely on NLS settings if you can avoid it.

Comment: date will be displayed to you in the format which is set by the NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter and to check the value of this parameter for your session you can use query : select value from nls_session_parameters where parameter='NLS_DATE_FORMAT'; To alter or change this format you use the alter session command as given in answer.

Comment: That's what I am trying to do. I tried to change the nls_date_formt using alter session command but it does not work. It is still displaying 10/28/2015 when I run the select sysdate from dual query.

Comment: Are you running that in the same session ?? where you executed alter session command ...because it will effect only on that session... other session will keep using instance default or database default format..

Comment: what tool are you using to run the query? I.e. Toad/SQL*Plus/SQL Developer/something else? It may be that you're running the query natively in the tool, which may well have settings that override the nls_date_format parameter. Have you tried running both statements as a script: ie. `alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd-mon-yyyy';` and `select sysdate from dual;`? That works for me in Toad - I get: `28-oct-2015`

Answer (score 2):

Oracle doesn't store a date as any format .. it just stores "a date".  you are viewing it/displaying it as  a different format.  Check your nls_date settings.

```
  SQL> select sysdate from dual;

  SYSDATE
  ---------
  28-OCT-15

  SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'

  Session altered.

  SQL> select sysdate from dual;

  SYSDATE
  --------------------
  28-oct-2015 11:00:56

  SQL>
```